# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_Error::getAll()

Tags: php, database, pear

I'm very bored, I backup the site, and I try to re-publish correctly but I have one php error...

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DB_Error::getAll()

check my code :

```
//renvoi toutes les lignes 
public function getAll($p_Req)
{
    global $db;
    return $db->getAll($p_Req);
}
```

I have reinstall php 5.2.17
pear 1.9.1 and DB packages 1.7.14

This is the good configuration for this site and I don't touch the code, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Please help

Comment: Please check and make sure that this method you're calling is in DB_Error class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you have instantiated in $db variable not PEAR:DB class but PEAR:DB_Error

You need to doublecheck the source of $db variable.

Comment: To add to this comment, the reason the $db variable is a PEAR:DB_Error class is likely because the connection failed for some reason.